# How can I sort a list of strings in ascending order of numeric part

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, numeric

I have a list of paths which have multiple numerical parts within them, here is part of it:

```
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG'
```

And using .sort() doesn't change it because it thinks it is already sorted.

Here is what it should be:

Expected result:

```
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG'
```

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sorts a list by **all** the parts of string found, where consecutive digits portions are to be considered as `int`, and the others as `str`:

```py
import re 

def split_str_int(s):
    a = re.split(r'(\d+)', s)
    a[1::2] = map(int, a[1::2])
    return a

newlist = sorted(mylist, key=split_str_int)
```

On your data:

```py
>>> newlist
['C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG']
```

Note also that the above will sort according to **all** of the parts found in the strings (both numerical and non-numerical). This is to comply with: "(...) which have multiple numerical parts".

For example:

```py
mylist = [
    'ab6cd45',
    'ab6cd2',
    'a6cd3',
    'ab4cd60',
    'a',
]
>>> sorted(mylist, key=split_str_int)
['a', 'a6cd3', 'ab4cd60', 'ab6cd2', 'ab6cd45']
```

Comment: This is nice.  What if the paths have different numbers in them; perhaps the regex should be updated to `(\d+)mm`, for example?

Comment: No, that's what the question asks for: "multiple numerical parts".

Comment: True; which (as you mention) begs clarification on the path corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

I belive you data is always like in this format.

```py
lst = ['C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG']

key =lambda e:int(e.split('\\')[-1].split('mm.')[0])
print(sorted(lst,key=key))
```

OUTPUT

```py
['C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG', 
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG']
```

Comment: What about using `os.path.basename` rather than splitting a string.  (Currently not portable to *nix)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library for sorting called natsort

```
from natsort import natsorted

lst = ['C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG',
'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG']

natsorted(lst)
```

This Returns:

```
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\1mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\2mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\3mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\17mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\18mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\19mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\20mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\21mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\29mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\30mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\31mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\38mm.JPG
C:\Python\Python310\Scripts\mockup_test\39mm.JPG
```

Answer (score 0):

`l.sort()` support custom sort function. you can achive your expect result by    bellow code snippet.

```
l = ['C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\17mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\18mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\19mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\1mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\20mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\21mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\29mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\2mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\30mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\31mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\38mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\39mm.JPG',
        'C:\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\mockup_test\\3mm.JPG']
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('\\')[-1][0:-6]))
print(l)
```